# Why SE search doesn't find what I'm looking for?

Tags: bug, search

I've searched [Gaming.SE for `battlefield 4 skill`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=battlefield%204%20skill). Results don't include anything relevant.

However, if you'd search for [same thing using Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=battlefield%204%20skill), number four result for me is [How is Skill calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139260/how-is-skill-calculated)

I'd expect it to be one of top results using internal search, yet it isn't.

Comment: It's the way the search works. Probably based on keyword weight/frequency etc. So the keyword "Battlefield" in your search is more prominent in questions and answers than "skill". If you search gaming site for "How is Skill calculated?" you get your result at the top. Search code and algos are black magic though, and as with Google you usually have to play around with keywords a bit in the search

Comment: @James well, two things, first of all I'd expect it to put results relevant to both `battlefield` and `skill` on top. Secondly, it's be great if it could recognize that search term `battlefield 4` is related to `[battlefield-4]` tag.

Comment: I know where you're coming from, but "battlefield 4" text is not necessarily always going to be in "battlfield-4" tag. You can search in tags using the square brackets, eg `[battlefield-4] skills` also returns your required question at the top - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=[battlefield-4]+skills

Comment: We append the most popular tag of a question to its title for display purposes (see the title on that question page). Google matches on this appended title. Internally, we search title without the appended tags, and tags as-is. This means that "battlefield 4" is not the same as "battlefield-4" tag unfortunately. I'm open to testing an adjustment to make this function more like Google. Thoughts?

Comment: @Haney: IMO tags should be indexed by search engine, maybe with priority even higher than title. Obviously you'd want to replace `"-"` with `" "` first.

Comment: @vartec they are currently indexed, but only tokenized on whitespace, aka the entity is "battlefield-4". We could analyze it as "battlefield 4" instead, but this would probably have side effects (I think of "C", "C++", and "C#" all becoming just "C")

Comment: @Haney: not full tokenizing, just considering adding `-`  a white-space char. Or indexing both terms, one with `-` and other with `-` replaced by space. Either way, that's implementation specifics. If you'd put what you've written in comments into an answer, I'll accept that.

Comment: @vartec - I think I want to take this on. I'm handing off a lot of the search work to a developer on my team, so I might use this as an easy-ish "get your feet wet" feature request to introduce them to search. :)